# Why don't tag feeds work with Opera's feed-reader?

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

Opening Stack Overflow family tag feed URLs do not cause Opera's built-in
feed-reader to ask if one wants to subscribe to the feed (it 
just displays a very big blob of text). Example tag feed 
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/perl.

The workaround is to save the content in a file with file
extension .xml and open this file in Opera. But this is
quite cumbersome and it would be nice if it worked.

For reference it does work with most other feed URLs that do not
have ".xml" at the end of the URL. Examples are
    http://feeds2.feedburner.com/deepfriedbytes,
    http://feeds.feedburner.com/netRocksFullMp3Downloads and
    http://www.cigital.com/silverbullet/feed
(.NET Rocks, Deep Fried Bytes and The Silver Bullet Security Podcast).

Comment: Have you checked the headers that those produce? Specifically when they get the Opera `user-agent`.

Comment: FYI: You can subscribe to feeds using the **Feeds | Manage Feeds** menu command.

Comment: @Helen: thanks for the tip. This makes for an easier work-around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text/html designation is a side-effect of IIS7 caching that we can't figure out. The request is INITIALLY served as text/xml, but IIS7 seems to ignore that when caching it, so all subsequent requests are text/html.

edit: this is now fixed.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a question on Server Fault :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like those feeds (at least the one you quoted) are sent out as `text/html`. Hard to blame Opera for simply trying to render the content.

EDIT: Firefox also receives them that way, but seems to apply more content sniffing to guess what it should do.

Comment: That was my guess.