# RSS feeds have wrong mime types

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t tag feeds work with Opera’s feed-reader?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17033/why-dont-tag-feeds-work-with-operas-feed-reader)

I've noticed that the RSS feeds (https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/USERID) are sent with **wrong header**. They are sent as `text/html` instead of `text/xml`, `application/xml` or `application/rss+xml`.

Does it have a reason? I think it's a bug.

Comment: Mimes are notoriously hard to work with.

Comment: Indeed - if you get them wrong, they often fail silently...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Jon: nominations for best comment ever have been submitted.

Answer (score 2):

[Blame it on IIS7](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17033/why-dont-tag-feeds-work-with-operas-feed-reader).